# Column formatting with json

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json

On a standard Date field that is inputted, can I display a full data format (example Friday, 23 March 2018 instead of 23/03/18) with Json to place in the column settings? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this doesn't seem to be possible. The [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) for Column formatting says that there are three options that we can use for formatting date objects:

```
toLocaleString() - Displays a date type fully expanded with date and time.
toLocaleDateString() - Displays a date type with just the date.
toLocaleTimeString() - Displays a date type with just the time.
```

**EDIT:**
In order to use this format, you would just need to paste the following code into the column Formatting box (you would just need to change the "operator" if you want other format):

```
{
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": {
        "operator": "toLocaleString()",
        "operands" : ["@currentField"]
    }
}
```

What you could do instead, is create additional calculated column with the following formula, and show that column instead of your date column:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([Datum],"DDDD"),", ",TEXT([Datum],"DD")," ",TEXT([Datum],"MMMM")," ",TEXT([Date],"YY"))
```

Comment: in case i were ok with one of the 3 above it would just be enough for me to type in the box 'toLocaleString()' ?

Comment: Please see my edits for the json code.

Comment: I have just tried your code and the date remains exactly the same. It was 23/03/2018 and after the code it is still 23/03/2018. I have tried the first operator and the second. The date column is set to display standard (and not friendly) dates. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the replies above is correct however the json formatting works only in the new experience view of the list